# Creating a list with customised names depending on the range in a for loop

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a basic list:

```
Number = 4

for i in range(1, Number):

    alpha = [f"alpha{i}" for i in range(1, Number)]
```

This produces alpha1, alpha2,...alphaN for whatever N is.

However I wish to customise this further. For example, I want it to produce a list of outputs with names such as alphaCR, alphaC2R, alphaC3R, or alphaRC, alphaRC2 etc etc. So depending on what N is, there is a total number of N(N-1) terms in this list. But I am having trouble in figuring out the logic in an approach like this. The issue with using numbers as in the current approach I have is that due to the number of terms will make it confusing

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `range(1, Number)` runs from `1` through `Number-1`, not `1` through `Number`.

Comment: Your list comprehension does not need to be in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to combine numbers `i` and letters as prefix `p` or suffix `s` where the number may be absent:

```
number = 4
[f'alpha{p}{i}{s}' for i in [''] + list(range(1, number+1)) for p in ['C', 'R'] for s in ['C', 'R'] if s != p]
```

Result:

```
['alphaCR', 'alphaRC', 'alphaC1R', 'alphaR1C', 'alphaC2R', 'alphaR2C', 'alphaC3R', 'alphaR3C', 'alphaC4R', 'alphaR4C']
```